# Ignore delimiters in quotes and excluding columns dynamically in csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I have awk command to read the csv file with `|` sperator. I am using this command as part of my shell script where the columns to exclude will be removed from the output. The list of columns are input as `1 2 3`

Command Reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/awkcsv

```
 awk -v FS='"| "|^"|"$' '{for i in $test; do $(echo $i=""); done  print }' test.csv
```

`$test is 1 2 3`

I want to print `$1="" $2="" $3=""` in front of `print` all columns. I am getting this error

```
awk: {for i in $test; do $(echo $i=""); done  {print }
awk:      ^ syntax error
```

This command is working properly which prints all the columns

`awk -v FS='"| "|^"|"$' '{print }' test.csv`

File 1

```
"first"| "second"| "last"
"fir|st"| "second"| "last"
"firtst one"| "sec|ond field"| "final|ly"
```

Expected output if I want to exclude the column 2 and 3 dynamically

```
first
fir|st
firtst one
```

I need help to keep the for loop properly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this strange field separator `'"| "|^"|"$'` ?  For me, it seems as a random sequence of characters.  It should not work at all, and I don't understand why do you think it should work.  Please explain.  As for the second code, `{print}` just prints an input line, without caring for fields or separators.  If you want separated by vertical line, use `awk -F\|` or  (backslash for shell escape, as vertical line has special meaning in bash and other shells).

Comment: '"| "|^"|"$'  is for field separator. If `|` comes in between quotes ignore them. Refer this link http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/awkcsv

Comment: I understand that it is for field separator.  I asked why this field separator would work.  "If | comes in between quotes ignore them." - ok, now I understand what are you trying to do but not why do you think your sequence of character would do it.  In any case, it would not work.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected output for it.

Comment: My script reads from another file as an input of what columns to exclude. I am getting the desired output but when I give the dynamic fields in the form of for loop. I am getting syntax error on for loop

Comment: 1. That `FS` is wrong. 2. That `for` syntax is not awk. What is the contents of the `$test`?

Comment: its `$test is 1 2 3` thank you

Comment: @JamesBrown Added my command reference. Would you mind to use it appropriate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNU awk (for `FPAT`):

```
$ test="2 3"                       # fields to exclude in bash var $test
$ awk -v t="$test" '               # taken to awk var t
BEGIN {                            # first
    FPAT="([^|]+)|( *\"[^\"]+\")"  # instead of FS, use FPAT
    split(t,a," ")                 # process t to e:
    for(i in a)                    # a[1]=2 -> e[2], etc.
        e[a[i]]
} 
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)             # for each field
        if((i in e)==0) {          # if field # not in e
            gsub(/^\"|\"$/,"",$i)  # remove leading and trailing "
            b=b (b==""?"":OFS) $i  # put to buffer b
        }
    print b; b=""                  # putput and reset buffer
}' file
first
fir|st
firtst one
```

[`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) is used as `FS` can't handle separator in quotes.

Comment: Hey James thanks for working out. But its printing all the columns `"first"|"second"|"last"
"fir|st"|"second"|"last"
"firtst`. I have commented the removing leading and trailing "

Comment: Are you using GNU awk? Is your data exactly as above?

Comment: Yes I am using GNU Awk. However the file doesn't have spaces after pipe. If I am keeping the space after pipe I am getting the desired output

Comment: Does it work if you remove the space and `*` in: `FPAT="([^|]+)|( *\"[^\"]+\")"` leaving: `FPAT="([^|]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`

Comment: I have used your regular expression with Ed's one line command

Comment: There's no reason to use that regular expression instead of the briefer one I provided in my answer given the input you've shown us.

Comment: @EdMorton Only reason that comes to mind is if some of the fields are not quoted, like `"needs|plumbing"|no need here`

Comment: There's other theoretical reasons too (e.g. escaped quotes within quoted fields) but the OP doesn't have any of those or she'd have shown us that in her sample input so no point making the regexp more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' '{print $1}' file
"first"
"fir|st"
"firtst one"

$ awk -v flds='1' -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' 'BEGIN{n=split(flds,f,/ /)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' file
"first"
"fir|st"
"firtst one"

$ awk -v flds='2 3' -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' 'BEGIN{n=split(flds,f,/ /)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' file
"second" "last"
"second" "last"
"sec|ond field" "final|ly"

$ awk -v flds='3 1' -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' 'BEGIN{n=split(flds,f,/ /)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' file
"last" "first"
"last" "fir|st"
"final|ly" "firtst one"
```

If you don't want your output fields separated by a blank char then set `OFS` to whatever you do want with `-v OFS='whatever'`. If you want to get rid of the surrounding quotes you can use gensub() (since we're using gawk anyway) or substr() on every field, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v OFS=';' -v flds='1 3' -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' 'BEGIN{n=split(flds,f,/ /)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", substr($(f[i]),2,length($(f[i]))-2), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' file
first;last
fir|st;last
firtst one;final|ly

$ awk -v OFS=';' -v flds='1 3' -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' 'BEGIN{n=split(flds,f,/ /)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", gensub(/"/,"","g",$(f[i])), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' file
first;last
fir|st;last
firtst one;final|ly
```

Comment: Hi Ed thanks for your answer. When I use your command its always printing all the columns. I got the output as `"first"|"second"|"last"< Row1
"fir|st"|"second"|"last" < Row2
"firtst Row 3` when `flds = '1'`

Comment: Then you're not using GNU awk or are running a very old one that doesn't support FPAT. What does `awk --version` tell you? The only other possibility is that your real input doesnt look like the input you posted - as you can see in my answer the script does produce the output you asked for given the input you provided.

Comment: Its GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: That's an extremely old version of gawk (about 5 years out of date) and doesn't contain FPAT nor a ton of other extremely useful functionality and bug fixes. Get a newer version of gawk.

Answer (score 1):

Vikram, if your actual Input_file is DITTO same as shown sample Input_file then following may help you in same. I will add explanation shortly too here(tested this with GNU awk 3.1.7 little old version of awk).

```
awk -v num="2,3" 'BEGIN{
    len=split(num, val,",")
                  }
   {while($0){
       match($0,/.[^"]*/);
       if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) !~ /\"\| \"/ && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) !~ /^\"$/ && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) !~ /^\" \"$/){
       array[++i]=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)
       };
       $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+1);
   };
   for(l=1;l<=len;l++){
       delete array[val[l]]
       };
   for(j=1;j<=length(array);j++){
       if(array[j]){
          gsub(/^\"|\"$/,"",array[j]);
          printf("%s%s",array[j],j==length(array)?"":" ")
                   }
       };
   print "";
   i="";
   delete array
   }'   Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** Adding a code with explanation too here.

```
awk -v num="2,3" 'BEGIN{ ##creating a variable named num whose value is comma seprated values of fields which you want to nullify, starting BEGIN section here.
    len=split(num, val,",") ##creating an array named val here whose delimiter is comma and creating len variable whose value is length of array val here.
                  }
   {while($0){ ##Starting a while loop here which will run for a single line till that line is NOT getting null.
       match($0,/.[^"]*/);##using match functionality which will look for matches from starting to till a " comes into match.
       if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) !~ /\"\| \"/ && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) !~ /^\"$/ && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) !~ /^\" \"$/){##So RSTATR and RLENGTH are the variables which will be set when a regex is having a match in line/variable passed into match function. In this if condition I am checking 1st: value of substring of RSTART,RLENGTH+1 should not be NULL. 2nd: Then checking this substring should not be having " pipe space ". 3rd condition: Checking if substring is NOT equal to a string which starts from " and ending with it. 4th condition: Checking here if substring is NOT equal to ^" space "$, if all conditions are TRUE then do following actions.
       array[++i]=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1) ##creating an array named array whose index is variable i with increasing value of i and its value is substring of RSTART to till RLENGTH+1.
       };
       $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+1);##Now removing the matched part from current line which will decrease the length of line and avoid the while loop to become as infinite.
   };
   for(l=1;l<=len;l++){##Starting a loop here once while above loop is done which runs from starting of variable l=1 to value of len.
       delete array[val[l]] ##Deleting here those values which we want to REMOVE from OPs request, so removing here.
       };
   for(j=1;j<=length(array);j++){##Start a for loop from the value of j=1 till the value of lengthh of array.
       if(array[j]){ ##Now making sure array value whose index is j is NOT NULL, if yes then perform following statements.
          gsub(/^\"|\"$/,"",array[j]); ##Globally substituting starting " and ending " with NULL in value of array value.
          printf("%s%s",array[j],j==length(array)?"":" ") ##Now printing the value of array and secondly printing space or null depending upon if j value is equal to array length then print NULL else print space. It is because we don not want space at the last of the line.
                   }
       };
   print ""; ##Because above printf will NOT print a new line, so printing a new line.
   i=""; ##Nullifying variable i here.
   delete array ##Deleting array here.
   }' Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Comment: can we parameter the separator?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain it little more. could try to help you on same then.

Comment: Can we parameterize the separator? Also can you explain what `if()` will do after the`match($0,regex)`

Comment: I added complete explanation now in my EDIT, so do you mean you want to send some parameter to field separator here? Could you please add some example what you are mentioning here please.